# Dedekind-infinite theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to share a point on which I was really stuck with you, in order for you to help me to see my mistake:

Here is the theorem:

**A set X is infinite if and only if it is equipotent (equivalent) to a proper subset of itself**

And here is my question.
The set of positive integers is infinite, and $\{1,2,3\}$ is a proper subset. However, there is no bijection between the set of positive integers and the given subset.

Where is my mistake? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Is that your real name, Grigori?

Comment: @Justpassingby no, of course

Comment: I appreciate the irony but be careful assuming the name of a living person. May I suggest Bernhard Riemann?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more precise statement of the theorem:

A set $X$ is infinite, if and only if *there exists* a proper subset $Y\subset X$, such that $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent.

So, $X$ is not expected to be equipotent to any proper subset of itself, but if $X$ is infinite, then it is equipotent to *some* proper subset of itself.

In your example, if $X=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, you can take $Y=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Every set other than the empty set has a subset to which it is not equipotent. So having a subset "smaller" than the original set is a property equivalent to being non-empty (in standard versions of set theory, anyhow).

The property of being infinite is characterised by having at least one proper subset which is equipotent with the original set.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you found *one* subset which is not equipotent with $\Bbb N$ does not mean there are no others. For example $\{2n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is equipotent with $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement should be read "if there exists a proper subset to which it is equipotent". As you have shown, that does not mean that every proper subset qualifies.